# Core Data access Z_PRIMARYKEY's Z_MAX data programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

Is it possible to access the Z_PRIMARYKEY table of core data programmatically?  I'm trying to find the Z_MAX value for a table/entity.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a Core Data SQLite store file directly using the standard C SQLite API but is poor practice to do so and virtually always unnecessary.

The collection operators and expression allow you to find sum, max, min and other common operations within a fetch. See [Core Data Programming Guide:Fetching Specific Values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html)

Comment: I found that "Fetching Specific Values" max: function actually returns the very last record in the table (rather than the max value in the column's data.)  So for what I was doing, it didn't work. I ended up using NSSortDescriptor.  So I should've asked the question differently. Thanks for the help, and hopefully this helps others out! :)

Comment: Properly implement a fetch for specific values returns a dictionary with one key-value and not a managed object. If you got the last "record" i.e. a managed object back, then you configured it incorrectly.